# Thread contemporary access to variables and synchronization mechanisms

Tags: multithreading, boost, asynchronous, mutex, pass-by-reference

I want to understand if the following code is correct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class background_task
{
private:
    std::vector<int> numbers;

public:
    background_task()
    {
        i=0;
        numbers.assign(6000,0);
    }

    void someLongComputation()
    {
        while (++i<200)
        {
            //boost::mutex::scoped_lock(formutex);
            // cout << "Thread inside: i= " << this->i << endl;
            numbers.at(0)=i;
            cout << "Thread inside numbers= " << numbers.at(0) << endl; 
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
        }
    }

    std::vector<int>& getNumbers()
    {
        return numbers;
    }

    int i;
};

background_task f;

void valuePicker()
{
    int j=0;
    while ( (j++) < 20 )
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
        cerr << "First number= " << f.getNumbers().at(0) << endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    boost::thread comp(boost::bind(&background_task::someLongComputation, &f));
    boost::thread value(valuePicker);

    comp.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This code should start two thread: one that makes someLongComputation (I added a timer sleeper to simulate the loooong computations which in fact are very short) and another thread which accesses at a different frequency to data contained in the computation thread.

I'm wondering now if this approach is correct, because it seems to me no mutexes are required, I would ask you how to make this code more thread-safe and correct, because I suppose I'm missing something...

Is it correct to pass a non-const reference or should be more safe to make it const?
Data created should never be written, only read...

Thanks! I hope with this thread to finally fix my beginners doubts on multithreading things...

Comment: thread safe is not something that is measured in degrees

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing to the shared array `numbers` is not thread safe.  The artificial `sleep` that you have inserted are likely masking the issue if this code is actually running successfully.

You need to have proper protection around the `numbers` vector, which is very difficult given the exact example because you expose this vector to clients through the public function `getNumbers()`.  Doing so means you cannot necessarily control how clients of the `background_task` actually interact with the data.

I would add a `boost::mutex` (as you have already commented out in the long computation function), and lock it in the long computation function (only when accessing the array to keep the scope of the lock small).  I would also remove the `getNumbers()` function and replace it with a function to get a value from the array at a specific index, such as `int getNumberAt(size_t idx);` and lock the `boost::mutex` there as well.

Comment: In my real code (this is just a simple abstraction) I would like to have read access to the whole vector<int>, so how can I do it correctly?

Comment: If you need read access to the entire vector then the only safe option is to expose the mutex and force via the API (and developer training) that they have to lock the mutex anytime they access the vector, and unlock it when they are done.  This brings in significantly more risk.